# Apple Watch (WatchKit) layout style library for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, watchkit, apple-watch

Layout for Apple Watch is based on placing objects to storyboard. Every new object is placed just under the previous one etc. There is also possible to use groups and align objects same way horizontally. (see details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CreatingtheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH4-SW1)) I would appreciate to have the same functionality on iOS - to place UIViews this way and define them same attributes like alignment, width relative to container etc. just like in WatchKit.

It is also similar with LinearLayout on Android. I found [CSLinearLayoutView](https://github.com/scalessec/CSLinearLayoutView) on github, but its very old and it doesn't use autolayout.

**Does any good library for this purpose exist?**

If not.. It looks very easy to implement this by myself, do you see any key problems or limitations which would make it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduced in iOS 9 as **UIStackView** - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/

Custom UIStackView implementation for iOS 7+
https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is or will be any addon for the Interface Builder itself, so you could use the same (ugly watchkit) constraints for iOS apps. AutoLayout for iOS is way better and more flexible to use than that WatchKit mess inside IB (Interface Builder of Xcode).

I do prefer to do most of the design work in my code so I don't have to worry if the IB will create some unnecessary stuff for me. If you want some drag and drop, you should use use IB and learn how to use AutoLayout.

**The interesting part:** 
If you want to create your design in code and want some library which is easy to use, you can try on of these: **[Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry)** (Obj-C) or **[SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit)** (Same Lib but in Swift). Both libs are very strong and up to date. I don't know if the dev implemented a custom alignment to center a subview in its superview. You should check that by yourself. :) If you like the VFL (Visual Format Language), like I do. You should search for a similar Lib or wait until I'm done with my project some day. :D I was inspired by SnapKits shiny syntax and started creating my own framework for VFL constraints. I also implemented the possibility to center my subview in its superview.

```
    let spacer1 = View(name: "spacer1")
    let spacer2 = View(name: "spacer2")

    let view1 = AutoLayoutView(name: "view1")
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view1.layer.cornerRadius = 50

    let view2 = AutoLayoutView(name: "view2")
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    view2.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    self.rootView.addSubview(spacer1)
    self.rootView.addSubview(spacer2)
    self.rootView.addSubview(view1)
    self.rootView.addSubview(view2)

    self.rootView.addConstraints { (add) -> Void in
        add.group({ (add) -> Void in
            add.normal.vertical.format("[view1(100)]").alignCenterHorizontaly
            add.normal.vertical.format("[view2(30)]")
            add.normal.horizontal.format("[view1(100)][spacer1]").alignCenterVerticaly
            add.normal.horizontal.format("[spacer1][view2(40)]").alignCenterY
            add.normal.horizontal.format("[view2][spacer2(==spacer1)]|")
        }, identifier: "GroupName")
    }
```

And with this we we get something like that:
[image: Landscape mode]
[image: Portrait mode]
There is still a lot work to do, so I can't public unfinished work yet.

I hope I could help you a little. :)

Comment: Yes, I know Masonry, I use it and I also prefer building UI from code :-) Autolayout is definitely more powerful and flexible than watchkit layout in IB but sometimes it would be fine to have something similar to use on iOS.  Maybe Android LinearLayout is more accurate example. I want linear collection of views and I want dynamically add and remove them. I have to rebuild constraints manually every time when using raw autolayout, so some library for that would be great. Do you understand what I mean?